# url rewrite in php

Tags: php, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_([^]+).htm/([0-9.]+)$ a.php?f=$1&t=$2&amt_from=$3 [NC]
```

I have form call a.php with 3 parameters. I am able to use the above rewrite rule, and a_b.htm/c does work.

My problem is when the user click a submit button on the form, they still see 
`a.php?f=$1&t=$2&amt_from=$3`

How do I fix that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules after the given one that match the requested URL?

Comment: Could you show the actual form or full contents of a.php?

Answer (score 1):

You need your form to generate the correct URL. This is only doable with some Javascript, but basically works like this:

```
<form action="a.php" method="GET" onsubmit="rewrite_form(event);">
   <input name=f value=123>
   <input name=t value=ABCABC>
   <input name=amt_from value=XYZXYZXYZ>
   <input type=submit>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function rewrite_form(e) {    
      var form = document.forms[0];   // .getElementById("form1");
      window.location = '' + form.f.value + '_' + form.t.value + '.htm/' + form.amt_from.value;            
      if (e && e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); }
      return false;
   }
</script>
```

So basically the form submit generates the nicer URL you want. If the browser doesn't support Javascript, it will fall back to the more elaborate GET-parameterized URL.

**Le Update**: The form element access was incorrect, you just need `document.forms[0].fieldname.value` usually. And I've moved the URL construction out into a separate function. The `onsubmit=` method works well enough with `event.preventDefault();` in Opera/Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: hey, mario, i am new to these. do u happen to have an example for my problem? what if i need to do some parse after i get $f/$t and using the parsed $f_p/$t_p in the url? thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know what you mean with parse. You already have the correct RewriteRule for the example JS url concatenation here. -- Or where/why do you want to parse it?

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake. all variables are good. i just working on them inside the php, but the variables are not changed. what u mean package with a callback. i am a js dummy. ty

Comment: With callback I just meant that you could move the `location=...;` assignment into a separate function. Then you could just use `<form onsubmit="rewrite_locatation(this)"` instead. But that's more for stylistic reasons, and wholly optional here unless you experience a conflict with the default submit method.

Comment: is this right? it doesn't work. sorry. really bad in js. <form name="cv" method="get" action="/sdir/fx.php" onsubmit="window.location.href=this.action + '/' + this.elements['f'].value+'_'+this.elements['t'].value+'.htm/'+this.elements['amt'].value;">

Comment: almost there, but keep repeating my f_t.htm, and the 2nd time i sumbit i got f_t.htm/f_t.htm/amt. how to fix please? <form name="cv" method="get" action="#" onsubmit="window.location.href=this.elements['f'].value+'_'+this.elements['t'].value+'.htm/'+this.elements['amt'].value; return false; ">

Comment: You probably need a separate function after all. Or instead of `<form onsubmit=` apply the url generation on the `<input type=button onclick="...">`. There the default submit event should be easier to catch. Otherwise you could try jQuery `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: would you please write me a solution? i know i am asking for too much. thanks a great deal. u can email me wintime58 at yahoo dot com. thanks thanks. you choose the solution for me.

Comment: Try the updated snippet. That works for me. The error was the `form.elements[]` syntax. -- Not sure about `return false;` still, but it seems to work with `e.preventDefault()` even without jQuery present. -- Also: you don't want to use `this.action`, but rather provide a fixed prefix in the function if that's necessary.

Comment: Use the Javascript error console to find out. Should you have other form field names than in your example, the function will be aborted.

Comment: i did a php header as a solution instead of js. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are still submitting with a `method="get"`, so the form creates that form of url..

Use post instead if you dont want the user to see the submitted values in the url

Comment: thanks neal. i understand that, but i wish user see a_b.htm/c in the address bar. how to make that happen?

Comment: you really cant... unless from your php script you check the url and if its not what you want then do a header redirect

Comment: hmm, that should be a good solution. lots of people do that? i am new to php stuff

Comment: hmm, i don't know how to do it